# Getting jsdoc and Crockford's design patterns to get along

Tags: javascript, oop, requirejs

I'm using Douglas Crockford's [design pattern](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) to implement private, privileged and public methods. It basically looks something like this (using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)):

```
define(function () {
    return function () {
        var that = {},

        _init = function () {
            // "constructor"
        },

        _privateFn = function () {
            return 42;
        };

        that.publicFn = function () {
            return 2 * _privateFn();
        };

        _init(arguments);

        return that;
    };
});
```

However, I'm having trouble getting the [jsdoc toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) to parse it correctly. I've played around with the `@name` and `@memberOf` annotations (like [here](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/issues/detail?id=313)), but no matter what I do, I just can't get the functions to show up.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe nobody knows anything (or seems to care). Let's bounty this sucker up.

Comment: It may not be the source of your problem, but I hope you are putting a `var` in front of each of those private functions!

Comment: actually, the semicolon after the _init-function should be a comma. thanks, i'll update the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. Here's how you do it:

```
/**
* @name MyModule
* @namespace
*/
define(['MyModule'], (function () {
    "use strict";

    var Clazz = function (config) {
        var that = {},

        /**
        * @private
        * @type number
        * @name MyModule#_privateField
        * @field
        */
        _privateField = 42,

        /**
        * Returns a private field
        * 
        * @private
        * @memberOf MyModule#
        */
        _privateFn = function () {
            return _privateField;
        };

        /**
        * Uppercases a string value.
        * 
        * @public
        * @name MyModule#publicFn
        * @function
        * @param {string} value The value to uppercase.
        */
        that.publicFn = function (value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        };

        return that;
    }

    return Clazz;
}));
```

Comment: +1 I just started using jsdoc3 and was initially bummed because I couldn't get anything other than the module description and name to be recognized by jsdoc. Your answer solved that.

Comment: See my answer below, this is much more difficult than using @lends.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar fun messing around with tags to try to get JsDoc Toolkit to output something sensible where things were being built up dynamically.

Even when [I got it working](http://jonathan.buchanan153.users.btopenworld.com/old/api.html), it ended up with odd quirks which required me to fiddle with the tags again and again, it looked unappealing and still wasn't a substitute for proper documentation - you might as well be reading those comments in the source code.

Honestly, the best thing I ever did was to take the time I was spending jumping through hoops with JsDoc Toolkit and use it to [write some real documentation](http://dombuilder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

In addition to the inherent benefits of any guided documentation written by people for people over auto-generated API docs, Sphinx has [JavaScript domain directives](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#the-javascript-domain) which allow you to document the [**final state** of the API](http://dombuilder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/genindex.html) which will be exposed to end users, rather than having some code attempt to make sense of the API by looking at trial-and-error comments littered about your code.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very interesting. I'll have to check it out next week.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while searching for a solution to the same problem. I ended up finding a better way to solve this if you don't care about documenting private methods/variables (which you probably shouldn't, given that they're really local variables and can't be accessed from anywhere else). It uses the @alias directive, which is new in JSDoc 3.

```
/**
* @name MyModule
* @namespace
*/
define(['MyModule'], (function () {
    "use strict";

    var Clazz = function (config) {
        /** @alias MyModule.prototype */
        var that = {};

        /**
        * Uppercases a string value.
        * @param {string} value The value to uppercase.
        */
        that.publicFn = function (value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        };

        return that;
    }

    return Clazz;
}));
```

Comment: I want document *all* my code, even if some of it may never end up in the public apidocs. I've switched to jsduck quite some time ago, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this existed when you tried it, but `@lends`is significantly nicer to use.

See:
http://usejsdoc.org/tags-lends.html

Example:

```
var Person = makeClass(
/** @lends Person.prototype */
{
    /** @constructs */
    initialize: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    say: function(message) {
        return this.name + " says: " + message;
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you don't have a constructor? This is not a valid documentation for a factory

Comment: If you have no constructor, then you would use \@name and \@namespace (if relevant) as they did above. \@lends and \@constructs are the best options for objects with constructors, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I consider Douglas Crockford's OOP patterns as anti-patterns. I learned hard way to not use them. This article summarize their drawbacks: http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php

So the solution is forget about Crockford's antipatterns and learn from developers, who actually write real code.

If you insist on privates, I suggest you to use Google Closure Compiler with its annotations, as you can see here: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html

Comment: Well, using one specific tool to circumvent the shortcomings of another really isn't what I would call a solution. Besides, after looking at the following article I'm not entirely sure a tool written by the Google developers is the way to go: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2009/11/12/google-closure-how-not-to-write-javascript/ (Granted, the article is rather old. But so is the one you linked.)

Comment: Crockord himself claims he's never had much use for classical OOP mimicry in JS. @n3rd, it could help if you explained how it's having parsing issues. I don't know much about JSDoc but it might become obvious if we see where it breaks down.

Comment: it doesn't break down, i works just fine. except that it doesn't generate documentation for my functions :-/

Comment: I can't stand Crockford's patterns either. However, this doesn't really answer the question, better off as a comment